# how to reset the value of static variable within a function in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
  int a = 10;
  static int sa = 10;

  a += 5;
  sa += 5;

  printf("a = %d, sa = %d\n", a, sa);
}


int main()
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    foo();
  }
}
```

I understand that "A static variable inside a function keeps its value between invocations". If I want to reset the value of "sa=10" later, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, every time `foo()` is called, both variables will be incremented by `5`. However `sa` will keep the value between the function calls:

```
i | a  | sa
0 | 15 | 15
1 | 15 | 20
...
```

to reset the value of `sa` just assign a value to this variable:

```
void foo()
{
  int a = 10;
  static int sa = 10;

  a += 5;
  sa += 5;

  // reset sa
  if (sa > 100) {
    sa = 10;
  }

  printf("a = %d, sa = %d\n", a, sa);
}
```

Comment: This will do it, but now write a cohesive (one line) definition of what the function does.  It is pretty nasty to describe — which suggests there's a flaw in the design.  The problems are inherent in the use of the function-scope `static` variable. This is not dissing your answer, which tackles the question, but it is commenting on the design implied or proposed by the question.